# Unable to visualize graph in tensorboard

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow, tensorboard

While writing the summary,

```
summary_writer1 = tf.train.SummaryWriter(logs_path, graph=tf.get_default_graph())
```

works fine and produces graph on tensorboard but doing

```
summary_writer2 = tf.train.SummaryWriter(logs_path, sess.graph())
```

produces the following error while running the code to train the model,

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "MultiLayerPerceptron.py", line 121, in <module>
    summary_writer2 = tf.train.SummaryWriter(logs_path, graph=sess.graph())
TypeError: 'Graph' object is not callable
```

also what's the difference between the default graph as in `summary_writer1` and graph in `summar_writer2`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no difference between the default graph and the `sess.graph`, they're the same exact graph.

The error is clear:

> 'Graph' object is not callable

The session object has a `graph` **member**, not a graph **method**.
Just remove the `()` from `graph=sess.graph()` and everything will work as you expect.